# Volante c# database engine: How we can binary search (or lookup) in Volante index?

Tags: c#, indexing

I will try to use C# Volante Database Engine in my private project. But provided example (DirectoryScan) ist only about reading whole index from start or from end. I need find for example first and others occurence(s), e. g.:

```
// c# pseudocode
result = index.GetFirst("lookingforThisString")
while(result != null) {
    doProcess(result);
    result = index.GetNext();
}
```

Have someone more examples on use this engine and indexes?

Answer (score 0):

A non-unique index can return an array of values using range arguments to the Get(from, till) command.

Here is a simple example:

```
class MyPersistentClass : Persistent
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

// Create the index. Must be non-unique to support duplicate keys
dbRoot.MyIndex = db.CreateIndex<string, MyPersistentClass>(IndexType.NonUnique);

// Put the data
dbRoot.MyIndex.Put("my string", new MyPersistentClass { Text="some value" });
dbRoot.MyIndex.Put("my string", new MyPersistentClass { Text="another value" });

// query the index to get multiple values. The range from and till values are the same
MyPersistentClass[] values = dbRoot.MyIndex.Get("my string", "my string");

// process the first occurrence
if (values.Length > 0)
{
   DoProcess(values[0]);
}
```